# How to hide a column in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, visual-studio, datagrid

I need to hide the `RevToDate` column in the `DataGrid` for any user who is not admin. How do I hide only this column?

```
 <asp:DataGrid runat="server" CssClass="tblResults" OnItemDataBound="dgList_ItemCreated" AllowSorting="true" OnSortCommand="dgCustomer_Sort" ID="dgCustomers" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="loading" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Customer.aspx?CustID={0}" DataNavigateUrlField="ID" DataTextField="AccountCode" HeaderText="A/C Code" SortExpression="AccountCode"></asp:HyperLinkColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CurrencyDesc" HeaderText="Currency" SortExpression="CurrencyDesc"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RevToDate" HeaderText="Rev To Date (Net)" SortExpression="RevToDate"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CreditLimitAmount" HeaderText="Credit Limit" SortExpression="CreditLimitAmount"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DiscountReviewDate" HeaderText="Discount Review Date" SortExpression="DiscountReviewDate" Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
            </Columns>
 </asp:DataGrid
```

I'm using this code to hide certain items:

```
 if (!CurrentUser.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        btnDelete.Visible = false;
        btnUpload2.Visible = false;
    }
```

But I am not sure how to hide the column. I can't set Visible to false in the CSS because it will hide the column from all users.

Comment: The good reason you can't do it in CSS is not the one you mention... if you do it in CSS, all users have the info in HTML, it simply doesn't show when page is rendered, so basically all users have access to the information, and that's what's wrong...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
 if (!CurrentUser.IsInRole("Admin"))
 {
     this.dgCustomers.Columns[2].Visible = false;
     btnDelete.Visible = false;
     btnUpload2.Visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: Will that hide all the columns? I only want to hide the second one (RevToDate)

Comment: @user2026041 you need to mention number in `Columns[2]` to hide specific column.

Answer (score 2):

Make it visible true from the aspx page like:

```
<asp:BoundColumn visible="true" DataField="RevToDate" HeaderText="Rev To Date (Net)" SortExpression="RevToDate"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

and then from code make it invisible:

```
if (!CurrentUser.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
         this.gdCustomers.Columns[2].Visible = false;
         btnDelete.Visible = false;
         btnUpload2.Visible = false;
        }
```

Where 2 is the column index in your gridview.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but still wanted to explain reason. 1] It seems you have copied and pasted code here because it doesn't match with OP question. 2] What is `i` in `Columns[i]` 3] OP wants to hide column based on user role. Hope it make sense.

Comment: Means u are trying to say, I should spoon feed the answer. ok

Comment: Please have look in ["How to answer on SO"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @RahulNikate better now?

Comment: Nah. I have made it more clear or i would say crystal clear by writing the code for aspx as well. Total spoon feed.

Comment: Read this again **"I need to hide the RevToDate column in the DataGrid for any user who is not admin"** and **you are doing perfectly reverse to it.** Bad spoon feed.

Comment: Sorry don't feel offended. Just tried to guide you on SO. This answers will be very helpful to future user's. So we have to be very clear about what we are writing here.

Comment: yes agreed totally. thanks for the right direction :)